# Asynchronous JS call prints fine but gives an 'undefined' error

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vue.js, undefined, axios

I'm struggling with asynchronous calls and I realized this question has been answered many times before, but I have tried many of the suggested approaches and have not been successful, so I would really appreciate if someone could help me. I also would like to note that I have been making great progress lately but I consider myself a beginner.

I have an asynchronous call to a database (in a controller.js file) that should return all the games from a 'Games' table and store it in a 'allGames' variable of the type Array:

```
async getAllGames ({ request, response }) {
  const allGames = await Game.all()
  return response.json({
    status: 'success',
    data: allGames
  })
}
```

When the page is loaded the function fetchAllGames is executed:

```
created () {
  this.fetchAllGames(this.myCallback)
},
methods: {
  myCallback (response) {
    this.allGames = response
  },
  fetchAllGames (callback) {
    axios
      .get('/fetch_games')
      .then(response => {
        callback(response.data.data)
      })
  }
}
```

All seems well, and here I should note that I am using VueJS.

When I try to print 'allGames' using

> {{ allGames }}

it works as expected, showing the array of all games from the database.

If I try

> {{ allGames[1] }}

I get the second game, also as expected.

If I try

> {{ allGames[1].id }}

I get the ID of the second game with hot reload. Now if I manually reload the page, even though the ID is still shown on the page, I get

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.allGames[1] is undefined"

in the console.

My problem with this is that I need to pass 'allGames' to another Component, and right now I am passing 'undefined'.

I really appreciate if any of you guys could shed me some light. I've been struggling for a while already and tried many different approaches. I have the same code in a different component and it seems to work fine. I'm sure I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `{{ allGames[1].id }}` VueJS instantly tries to render the id of the first element, which does not exist yet when you initially render your page, because the data is still being loaded in the background.

You either need to use the `v-for` directive or guard the rendering `{{ if allGames.length ? allGames[1].id : '' }}`

In regards to hot-reloading: Hot reloading works differently than a refresh of the page. I am no expert, but i would assume that the VueJS data is not getting cleared properly when parts of the site are hot reloaded

Comment: I think you mean `v-if` directive. I have tried using `v-if="allGames.length"` and got the same result.

Comment: Tried `{{ allGames.length ? allGames[1].id : '' }}` and got exactly the same result again.

Comment: No. I assumed that this was an array and you want iterate through it. Maybe try `{{ allGames.length > 1 ? allGames[1].id : '' }}` since you try to access the second element.

Comment: Also, if the data is still being loaded when the page is rendered, how can the array be printed? I mean, even `allGames[1].id` prints fine, but I get the error message and the data is sent as `undefined` to the child component. I can't understand also why when I use `allGames[1]` it doesn't throw me the error and when I use `allGames[1].id` it does, but saying that `allGames[1]` is undefined (without the `id`).

Comment: Ok, using your last suggestion I got something different: this time I still got the same error, but the data was passed correctly.

Comment: Pretty sure it is becaused undefined values are printed as empty strings, but if you access the `id` on a undefined object JavaScript throws you an error. Do you have `allGames` defined in the `data ()` segment of your parent component?

Comment: I will play a little bit more with these options and will get back here. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Yes, it's defined properly.

Comment: Okay. Then try to use a watcher on `allGames` in your child component and `console.log` the input to this watcher.

Comment: Not sure what you mean: I tried `watch: { allGames: function(){ console.log (this.allGames) } }`

Comment: One more thing: if I have `<p>{{ allGames[1].id }}</p>` the result is passed correct to the child. If I simply comment this line it's passed as undefined, even if I add, for example, `{{ allGames.length > 1 ? allGames[1].id : '' }}`

Comment: Would it be possible for you to create a jsfiddle? It is really hard to follow what is going on.

Comment: Not sure how I would do it so that it can make a call to a database and have multiple components. Will have a look. Anyway thanks for your help so far

Comment: When I went back to check the problem wasn't there anymore. I guess I inadvertently changed some other part of the code that fixed this issue. Thanks for your help.